# VBA collection with 2 or more fields

Tags: sql, vba, excel, recordset

I'm using a Collection to store data from a recordset in VBA. The recordset has two fields.

I'm using a collection because I want to utilise its ability to prevent duplicates by using the key parameter. I'm running an SQL query to generate the recordset many times and a lot of the results will be identical to the previous, but some will be different. I want to capture a collection of the unique results from each recordset.

I can do this currently using the following:

```
        rs.Open sql_vehicles, cn

        If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then

            Do While Not rs.EOF
                On Error Resume Next
                value = rs.Fields("EVN").value
                catalogue_Tags.Add Item:=value, Key:=value
                rs.MoveNext
                On Error GoTo 0
            Loop
        End If
```

which all resides in a for loop generating a new recordset each time which may or may not be different.

This will give me a collection with unique values from the "EVN" field in the recordset, but I need to be able to store the second field in the recordset as well, but I want to still avoid duplicates of the EVN field!

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Why not combine the different recordsets into a single query (UNION) and harness the power of SQL to do the work for you with DISTINCT or GROUP BY?

Comment: Brilliant, never thought of doing it that way. Thanks!

Comment: (I can't tell if that's sarcasm or not :P ) If you can provide more information about your queries and table structure, I can sum that advice up in an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you can just use 2 collections to get 2 unique lists...

```
value = rs.Fields("EVN").value
catalogue_Tags_EVN.Add Item:=value, Key:=value
value = rs.Fields("ABC").value
catalogue_Tags_ABC.Add Item:=value, Key:=value
```

I just notice your requirement is slightly different then I read the first time...
Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to your project and use a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
Dim evnValues as new Scripting.Dictionary ' this will actually be a dictionary of dictionaries.
```

inside the loop do this...

```
ABCvalue = rs.Fields("ABC").value
if not evnValues.Exists(value) then
    ' sub dictionary does not exist yet. initialize the list for this evn value
    evnValues(value)=New Scripting.Dictionary
end if 
evnValues(value).item(ABCValue)=ABCValue ' accumulate a list of the ABCValues relative to the unique evnValue.
```

At the end you will have a dictionary with the Names of the top level being your unique EVN values and the sub value will be a collection of 1 or more ABC values.